# Is it proper to reference your project name inside your Django project?

Tags: python, django, import

I'm using Django and I'm wondering whether it's proper to use myapp.models, opposed to myproject.myapp.models, or in INSTALLED_APPS, should the FULL NAME be used myproject.myapp or is it alright to just use myapp for it's name? I am wondering because if I were to change the project name using the latter method it would break my app, but I'm not sure that just because the former method works that it is correct. Could someone clear this up for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Ask 15 Django developers about this and you'll get 20 opinions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I'm struggling to think of more than four or five possible opinions; could you please publicly document some of the more esoteric opinions which might be vouchsafed in such research?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is not encouraged to reference your apps using your project name.  I say this because as of Django 1.4 this will not work with a default Django project.  You can read more about this here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

A quote from that:

"If settings, URLconfs and apps within the project are imported or referenced using the project name prefix (e.g. myproject.settings, ROOT_URLCONF = "myproject.urls", etc), the new manage.py will need to be moved one directory up, so it is outside the project package rather than adjacent to settings.py and urls.py."

I would recommend against it since it would mean messing with the default project structure, not a huge deal, but increased unnecessary work.

I would also recommend against it since it couples your apps to your project, which imho goes against the philosophy of Django which advocates reusable, decoupled apps.